# Does BigQuery have a rule based or cost based optimizer or other?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am curious which type of optimizer it uses so I can optimize my database and queries to fit.

I know cost based is designed to determine the most efficient way to carry out a SQL statement, but it can’t reach do this without good, up-to-date statistical information on the data being accessed. With the cost-based approach, the optimizer factors is statistical information about the contents of the particular schema objects (tables, clusters, or indexes) being accessed.

The rules-based optimizer is an approach without statistical information, but this approach is less intelligent than the cost-based approach. With the rules-based approach, the optimizer chooses an execution plan based a set of rules about what types of operations usually execute faster than other types.

I believe its cost based but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone provide me more information on why it could be one or the other?
Thank you!

Comment: Is this a programming question? Or are you just curious about BigQuery internals?

Comment: Curious about BigQuery internals

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic rule for saving cost in BigQuery. The best way is to follow [BigQuery best practices: Controlling costs](http://BigQuery%20best%20practices:%20Controlling%20costs)

Please see below some rules which I find quite useful:

**Rule 1**

> Avoid SELECT *
>   Best practice: Query only the columns that you need.

**Rule 2**

> Sample data using preview options
>   Best practice: Don't run queries to explore or preview table data.

**Rule 3**

> Price your queries before running them
>   Best practice: Before running queries, preview them to estimate costs.

**Rule 4**

> Limit query costs by restricting the number of bytes billed
>   Best practice: Use the maximum bytes billed setting to limit query costs.

**Rule 5**

> Partition data by date
>   Best practice: Partition your tables by date.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly, If you want to learn more on how BigQuery optimize query under the hood see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UueWySREWvk), please feedback if this is what you were looking for

Comment: This article talks about the difference between the two algorithms
http://its-all-about-oracle.blogspot.com/2015/03/cost-based-optimizer-vs-rule-based.html
I'm curious to know which it is before I start using BigQuery

Comment: I suggest you watch the video I put in my post and than refine your question

Comment: Is there a video? The link is empty. Also: Clustering. https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b

Comment: @anon if you find my answer or comment helpful please consider accepting/voting on it